# Show that if an analytic function f satisfies f(2x) = f(x)^2, then it is the exponential

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytical function such that $f(2x) = f(x)^2$. Suppose $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset (0, \infty)$. Show that $f(z) = \exp(\lambda z)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Hint: Show that $f(0) = 1$ and that if $f(1) = e^λ$ then $f(\frac{1}{2^n}) = e^{\frac{\lambda}{2^n}}$

I've managed to prove both hints:

1. $f(0) = f(0)^2$, and solving this, we have that $f(0) = 0, 1$. But it can't be $0$ by definition.
2. $f(\frac{1}{2^n}) = f(\frac{2}{2^{n+1}}) = f(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})^2$. And using induction, we obtain that $f(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}) = e^{\frac{λ}{2^{n+1}}}$.

But i'm not quite sure how to use these Hints. I have tried the following way:

Let $g(z) = f(z) - e^{f'(0)z}$. Now $g$ is clearly analytic and can be written as $g(z) = \sum a_n z^n$, with $a_n = \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. We wish to show that $g^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all n.

Suppose the following is true: $f'(z) = f'(0)f(z)$. Then, by induction, we obtain that: $f^{(n+1)}(z) = f^{(n)'}(z) = f'(0)^{n+1}f(z)$. And with, this we can prove that: $g^{(n)}(0) = f^{(n)}(0) - f'(0)^n = 0$.

But i also can't seem to prove that $f'(z) = f'(0)f(z)$.

How should i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably meant to use (and maybe prove) the following fact:

> Let $g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic and let $(z_n) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence converging to $0$. If $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) \, g(z_n) = 0$, then $g \equiv 0$.

The function $g(z) = f(z) - e^{\lambda z}$ satisfies $g \left( \frac{1}{2^n} \right) = 0$, so it follows that $g(z) \equiv 0$, hence $f(z) \equiv e^{\lambda z}$.

Comment: How do you get the recursion equation for $g$? I can see it for the quotient $g(z)=f(z)e^{-f'(0)z}$ that  $g(\frac1{2^n})-1=0$, but not for the difference version.

Comment: @LutzL As proved in OP, $f \left( \frac{1}{2^n} \right) = \exp \frac{\lambda}{2^n}$, so $g \left( \frac{1}{2^n} \right) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Then I was thinking too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Less clever, but enjoyable, solution: Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n.$ Then

$$f(2z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n2^nz^n,\,\,\,\,\, f(z)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_ka_{n-k})\,z^n.$$

It follows that $2^na_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_ka_{n-k}$ for each $n.$ Now we know $a_0 = f(0) = 1.$ Set $a_1= \lambda.$ If we move along for $n=2,3,\dots,$ the pattern

$$\tag 1a_n = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$$

emerges. We already know this holds for $n=0,n=1.$ If you assume it holds for $n,$ you'll see, very pleasingly, that it holds for $n+1.$ Thus $(1)$ holds for all $n,$ and the desired result follows.